# How do you convert a variable from an integer to a string in base R?

Tags: r

I've just started using R and I have no aptitude for coding.  I don't speak the language so I can't follow the examples I've seen (sorry!).

I have a variable called `Gender` which has levels `1` and `2`, which I created like this:

```
factor(Gender, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Male","Female"))
```

It appears that the 1's and 2's for the variable are registering as "integers" but I want them to be registered as string variables (ie nominal values).

How do I tell R to change 1 and 2 to `"1"` and `"2"`, please?

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this? The `factor` class stores the data as integer internally, but that does not mean stats procedures e.g. `lm` will treat the variable as quantitative. Because it is a factor variable, it will already be recognized as categorical rather than quantitative.

Comment: I am just learning R at the moment so I'm trying different things out. I made a graph and it showed Gender in the legend as intervals between 1 and 2 so I thought it's best to get the housekeeping done before I do anything else and would teach me what to do in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `as.character(...)` to treat objects as character strings.